# Unable to do clustering in Tigase Server on CentOS6.10 64 Bit

Tags: java, server, tigase

I am trying to do clustering in CentOS 6.10

My versions of Jdk , JRE=

`java version "1.8.0_60"
javac 1.8.0_60`

This is my config.tdsl file  for ip =192.168.4.109

```
admins = [
    'admin@imrggn.com'
]
'config-type' = 'default'
debug = [ 'server' ]
'default-virtual-host' = 'imrggn.com'
dataSource () {
    default () {
        uri = 'jdbc:derby:tigasedb;create=true'
    }
}
'audit-log' () {}
http () {
    setup () {
        'admin-password' = 'tigase'
        'admin-user' = 'admin'
    }
}
pubsub () {
    trusted = [ 'http@{clusterNode}' ]
}
'sess-man' () {
    'audit-log' () {}
}



'dns-resolver' {
-'tigase-resolver-class' = -'tigase.util.DNSResolverDefault'
-'tigase-primary-address' = -'192.168.4.109'
-'tigase-secondary-address' = -'192.168.4.109'
}

stun (class: tigase.stun.StunComponent) {
-'stun-primary-ip' = -'mc2.imrggn.com'
-'stun-primary-port' = 3478
-'stun-secondary-ip' = -'hey-sjain-l'
-'stun-secondary-port' = 7001


}

'cluster-mode' = true
'cluster-nodes' = [ -'mc2.imrggn.com', -'mc1.imrggn.com']
```

When I run Wireshark  ie tcp.port==5277 , I see nothing there at all where the default port is 5277 only , hence it shows no value over there on neither of the machines

But `lsof -iTCP:5277` shows `java    21155 root  175u  IPv6 733910      0t0  TCP *:5277 (LISTEN)`

My ip = `192.168.4.109` hostname = `mc2.imrggn.com` 
And for the other machine is My ip = `192.168.4.111` hostname = `mc1.imrggn.com`

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to your database setup (`uri = 'jdbc:derby:tigasedb;create=true') - for the clustering to work (and make sense) you would have to use a database, that would be available to all cluster nodes (in this case MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQLServer or MongoDB).

The reason is two-fold:

- if you would use local DerbyDB on all nodes then all information would be local (i.e. you would have different list of users on each node
- (more important) Tigase uses *cluster auto-discover* which utilizes the database (each node announces it's availability via shared database)